# Given a string of words, can you construct a wordladder

Tags: java, recursion

I'm given a start word, a goal word, and a string array of words I'm allowed to use.  I'm supposed to use recursion to return whether or not I can construct a word ladder between the first word and the last word using at least one word from the given string array.

Recursion is very challenging to me, so I'm really lost/confuse as to how to approach this problem.

Comment: The homework tag is obsolete and should not be used anymore. If it is a good question no need for this tag. If it is a bad question, edit it to make it a good one.

Comment: Just removing the tag is not the enough. I think...

Comment: Well, maybe you should read up on what [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is then.

Comment: Your first step should be to research the topic. I've downvoted your question as it is apparent that you've not taken that first step.

Comment: @Erica Fischer-Colbrie I don't know why this question was so badly voted. If she doesn't know what recursion means or maybe the teacher meant something different, we could kindly ask for more info and and see if we can clarify the requirements. Guys software is about communication also, remember that. I don't know but I don't agree with all the negative votes. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each word link it to a list of all possible siblings.  Then start building a tree of all possible ladders...starting from the first.  If you hit the goal return the path between the two.  You can use recursion on navigating the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion consists in calling a function from inside itself. You need always to specify a exit condition (or you'll get an stack overflow). The rest depends on your needs:

```
class Myclass {
    public static int doSomething(int a) {
        if (a < 10) {
             doSomething(a + 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.printl(Myclass.doSomething(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay sorry I wasn't clear, I know what recursion is I'm just really bad at it and confused.

Answer (score 0):

What @user2103249 said.  For something like this your recursive routine should probably return the successful path.  Something on the order of:

```
public String[] canFindPath(String[] pathSoFar) {
    for (characters in last word of pathSoFar) {
        for (all possible modifications of the character) {
            if (modifying the character produces a word in the word list but not already in pathSoFar) {
                Create new pathSoFar copy, with the one additional word;
                if (additionalWord == goalWord) {
                    return newPathSoFar;
                }
                String[] result = canFindPath(newPathSofar);
                if (result != null) return result;
             }
         }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Though there are a dozen different approaches.

Initially constructing a map of possible transitions from wordA to wordB in the word list would speed things along, as you could quickly index through the possibilities rather than having to search for each one on each step.